# Download files from sharepoint using python failing with different URL

Tags: python

I am trying to download a file from sharedpoint's url using python, which is working for one url and causing trouble for another url. I am not able to figure out the reason failing for another url.

but I would like to fix it using the same manner if its possible where I am passing the user credential.

```
from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
```

## working for this URL

sh_url       = r'https://dumy.com/abc/def/temp'

rel_url      = r'/abc/def/temp/Shared%%20Documents/pqrs/abc.xml'

## url CREATING PROBLEM

sh_url1 = r'https://dummy1.com/:x:/r/sites/st'

rel_url1= r'/:x:/r/sites/st/Shared%%20Documents/abcd/abc.xlsx?d=w5528f0eb1e4302ad00be6abeb67&csf=1&web=1&e=DUM1'

try:

```
  user_cred = UserCredential(uname, pass_word)

  ctx = ClientContext(sh_url).with_credentials(user_cred )

  with open(input_file_path, "wb") as local_file:

     file = ctx.web.get_file_by_server_relative_url(rel_url)
  
     file.download(local_file)

     ctx.execute_query()
```

except:

```
   print( f'{sys.exc_info()[0]}')
```

I had found that file->server_relative_path->Decodedurl matched with 'relative url' for passed url(rel_url)
and same is coming as None for failed URL. But I am not able to understand why it is not working for 2nd URL(rel_url1)

Any suggestion or guidelines highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance